# Build an RSA encoder

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

Your task is to build a function in any language that takes a message `m`, an encryption `e`, and a modulus `k` (all positive integers), and takes `m` to the power of `e` modulo `k`. Your solution must not be a theoretical one, but one that would work on a reasonable computer such as your own, for RSA keys of currently used sizes such as 2048 bits.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage? Does this implicitly forbid using big integer libraries unless they come with documented guarantees about their memory usage?

Comment: (And if you're going to post a challenge about RSA, why not make it interesting by asking for an implementation of *real* RSA as opposed to academic useless-for-protecting-secrets RSA?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Big-integer libraries are fine. The main point of the limit is to prevent people from trying to store the entire exponentiated number and then evaluating it modulo `m`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Also, you can pose the question that includes PKCS #1 if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python – 5

Python 3 built-in function pow have third parameter. So Python 3 already have built-in RSA encoder

```
r=pow
```

Comment: Looks like we have a winner. I didn't know that. :\

Comment: In fact, the solution has a length of 0. Just use function `pow` for RSA encoding/decoding

Comment: Nope, it's still length 3 because you need to describe it. :P

Comment: Imho, this solution has a char count of 5. By just providing `pow`, the criteria 'build a function' is not satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first attempt at actually golfing something here:

## Python – <s>69</s> <s>61</s> 55

```
r=lambda m,e,k:1 if e==0 else m**(e%2)*r(m*m%k,e/2,k)%k
```

This is a simple exponentiation by squaring algorithm.

---

**02/15 13:17 – 61:** Used lambda notation. 
**02/22 15:44 – 55:** Removed some brackets as per grc's suggestions.

Comment: I believe the question specifies that the function should be named `RSA`

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear on my part.

Comment: You can save a few chars by removing unnecessary spaces and brackets: `r=lambda m,e,k:1if e==0 else m**(e%2)*r(m*m%k,e/2,k)%k`. And you might also be able to do this, but I haven't tested it: `r=lambda m,e,k:e<1or m**(e%2)*r(m*m%k,e/2,k)%k`. It uses `e<1` instead of `e==0` and `or` instead of `if ... else`.

Comment: Doesn't % have precedence over *?

Comment: In most C-derived languages, `*/%` have equal precedence and are evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: Huh. I seem to have forgotten that. I generally use brackets where it might be ambiguous anyway, as I've been burned too many times by strict left-to-right evaluation to forget.

Comment: @grc: I'm pretty sure `e<1` will return `True`, not `1`.

Comment: @Joe Zeng: Yes, but `True` behaves as `1` when it is used with arithmetic operators.

Comment: Well, I learned something new. Will "or" also default to bitwise or when working with numbers?

Answer (score 0):

### java (83 chars)

if input is of BigInteger type:

```
public BigInteger r(BigInteger m,BigInteger e,BigInteger k){return m.modPow(e,k);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
!¡o%⁰*³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZK5DRVRDEVrISAh8vXujpAICBAFUAodINEBpdDIcIbk/xmN312O3@fv3748z4c/P79@/Pvj16c/v5/nkUdWz57s0USUZ7tmZb2Wd9Xl69GpsPch5xR9mZLixrrKI6azr@@u50pbIau4G@8rV9S@f5e7M8uPTInDhlIb4Z5TupAquysWyXHz8WWs67y7BxV3PmZkxJ7vZqcVtp602JxsFM8vjvCNgM@tyOYeanHG8FD5jPh@XfNanPsOI2sYBT40NrMML@TNw8oGSm9Ky9osMpFRw6Q6tFqyevVWCiZgcE6QpGkKzOJ1pyizCtcCaYTpf60C7r1g0FcSLQC8zKMZEPcFiLzGqh2LYhNURR8yeAA2DNtXjFW2WbMi9jQ5a0Sdtq3WAYxiHTxSX@ms5QXCgm6je1k4AdL/Q2QFRBJcOpg6bgDXgfX4i4/epDPKzDmta3nPJR/m/ioCDsrLYRu0r94SzRb27uHWxPwD)

Function that takes arguments: arg1=m (message), arg2=k (key/modulus), arg3=e (exponent/encryption).

Encoding takes about 10 seconds on [Try it online!] with a message of `12345678910`, a 2048-bit key/modulus of `17335246217810680499565282364130282347913694411139706552337646969996795185310539972695213589521948877888710148108314183322475193115466538523720272848165926667358225384343389288464059692412384746831929390686202279817642231618920311152771862965772849228722380926373552800043250590230507345247504584516585217552163181827225685419709962073929610117852078754818132187957128758451536498778247147713136878727238232838512570562685513074673965992921930197584545660069134797478016576085619884280636191861425890311213983668804147423192923778212236303196414996652277121672303217925415867248268691221399027188630076689585126618899`, and exponent/encryption of `65537`.

Decoding is significantly longer when (as is usual) the decryption exponent d is much larger than the encryption exponent e.  But we can check that it works using small values: m=`123`, k=`257` and e=`7` (for which the decryption exponent d=`55`):
[Try encoding](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQwnzVR40btA5t/v//v6GR8X8jU/P/5gA)
[Try decoding](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQwnzVR40btA5t/v//v7HpfyNT8/@mpgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4 bytes (8 nibbles)

```
=_`.@%*_
```

```
=_`.@%*_        # full program
=_`.@%*_$@      # with implicit args added
  `.            # repeatedly apply (while results are unique)
    @           # starting with arg2:
      *_$       #   multiply arg2 by result-so-far
     %   @      #   and modulo by arg1
=_              # finally, return result at index given by arg3
```

Full program that takes arguments: arg1=k (key/modulus), arg2=m (message), arg3=e (exponent/encryption).

Encoding is fast (screenshot below shows a message of 12345678910, a 2048-bit key/modulus, and exponent/encryption of 65537).
[image]
Decoding is significantly longer when (as is usual) the decryption exponent d is much larger than the encryption exponent e. But we can check that it works using small values: m=123, k=257 and e=7 (for which the decryption exponent d=55).
[image]